# How to refer or call a vector that was created in other while loop in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a small program in C++ to test the performance of insertion sort and other sorting algorithms. I would like to store a very large numbers in a txt file and let my program read it first and store each number into a vector. So the sorting algorithms could easily handle such vector.

But I came across an issue, that I don't know how to call the vector(num1) in my insertion sort part. As the vector was initialized in a while loop prior to the sorting.The compiler cannot identify it so my program can not proceed. So I would appreciate anyone to give me some advice to solve this issue or maybe give your thoughts about my codes. Thanks very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //To read file: 
ifstream num("test.txt");
char num_arry[1000000];
if (!num)
{
    cout << "File load error,please check if file exist" << endl;
}
while (!num.eof())
{
    num >> num_arry;
    int number = stoi(num_arry); // convert char to int     
    vector<int> num1;  //set a new vector to store file data numbers
    num1.push_back(number); // push int in the vector

}

// Insertion sort start:
for (int i = 1; i < num1.size(); i++) {
    int element = num1[i];
    int j = i;
    while (num1[j - 1] > element) {
        num1[j] = num1[j - 1];
        j = j - 1;
        num1[j] = element;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < num1.size(); i++) {
    cout << num1[i] << " ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `num1` is defined local to the `while` loop, it will be re-initialized and decayed per loop round

Comment: off topic: watch out for `while (!num.eof())`. It doesn't work quite the way you'd like. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Actually, I am debugging this issue, thanks for letting me know this!

Answer (score 3):

Simply move the `vector<int> num1` to *before* the `while` loop. That way, it exists beyond that loop, specifically into the region of code below where you want to use it.

What you have wouldn't work in any case even *if* the scope survived the end of the loop, since the vector is created anew in every single iteration of said loop - it would end up being a vector with just the last element in it.

In other words this (simplified form):

```
while (!num.eof()) {
    vector<int> num1;
    num1.push_back(something);
}
// Cannot see num1 here.
```

would become:

```
vector<int> num1;
while (!num.eof()) {
    num1.push_back(something);
}
// num1 is usable here.
```

---

You may also want to reconsider loading your number into a character array then calling `stoi` on it (unless you have a specific reason for doing so). The C++ stream stuff is perfectly capable of reading directly into a non-character data type, such as with:

```
vector<int> numArray;
{
    int number;
    while (numInputStream >> number)
        numArry.push_back(number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Moving ahead the initialization works!!  I also tried your advice, however, if I don't use char array the stream will not work properly.